# Retrieve current iCloud account information in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud

How to get current active iCloud account username in iOS device to show it in my application?

*Code from the comment below by OP*

```
NSURL ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

if (ubiq) 
{ 
    NSLog(@"iCloud access at %@", ubiq.user); // TODO: Load document... 
} 
else 
{ 
    UIAlertView alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No iCloud access" message:@"Please set your iCloud account in Setting-iCloud" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]; // [alert show]; NSLog(@"No iCloud access"); 
}
```

If you know how to to show iCloud account username please tell me. I have already searched for this, but I could not find any answer for my case.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a *Show me da codez!!!* site. So some efforts. Post some code if you have.

Comment: i dont know the code...i already search for this in google but no solution...

Comment: the only code i use it is using  this code :

NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                       URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
        if (ubiq) {
            NSLog(@"iCloud access at %@", ubiq.user);
            // TODO: Load document...
        } else {
            UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No iCloud access" message:@"Please set your iCloud account in Setting-iCloud" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
           // [alert show];
            NSLog(@"No iCloud access");
        }

but it return with nil..

Comment: You can edit your original question and add your code in it, rather than posting the code in comments.

Comment: thank you devraj.....for editing my question...this is my first time i post a question in stackoverflow...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do it. The details of the iCloud account are not available to third party apps. All you can find out is whether iCloud is available to your app. The username is not available via any public API. The ubiquity container URL does not encode the iCloud user name, and neither does `NSFileManager`'s `ubiquityIdentityToken`.